# Does jqGrid or jQuery have the functionality of caching DOM changes inside a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, jqgrid

For example, if we have select/option/dropdown box in html. 1) is faster than 2) in jQuery if we have an array size of 5000.

1) make a string first:

```
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i<an_array.length; i++) {
  str +='<option value="' + an_array[i] + '">' + an_array[i] + '</option>';
}
jQuery("#my_select").append(str);
```

2) append every time:

```
for (var i = 0; i<an_array.length; i++) {
  jQuery("#my_select").append(
    jQuery('<option></option>').val(an_array[i]).html(an_array[i])
  );
}
```

My question is: does jQuery or jqGrid have such kind of function that makes a cache string first and then post everything on html when done? Or are we already using this way in jqGrid? The reason I am asking this question is that seems jqGrid is really slow when I have more than 500 columns. This is just like in C. You can either auto flush to a file every time you do fprintf, or you can manually flush it when you are done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it said several times in the jQuery documentation that cached objects should always be used when re-iterating the same DOM content multiple times because it takes more processing power to walk the DOM each time.

I would code your solution thus:-

HTML

```
<select id="my_select"/>
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
//an array to use for demonstration
var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

var $frag = $();
$.each(arr, function () {
    $frag = $frag.add($("<option/>").val(this).text(this));
});
$("#my_select").append($frag);
```

Note the line **var $frag = $();**. The **$()** creates an empty jQuery object, and I have prefixed the variable name **$frag** with a **$** simply to remind myself that it's a jQuery object rather than a text string.

Hope that answers your question satisfactorily.

Best regards,
Alan